# SublimeREPL error in Windows

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, read-eval-print-loop, pry, sublimerepl

I'm trying to set up my environment for Ruby development. I've installed Ruby and Pry on my system. I want to using SublimeREPL but I'm having issues getting it working.

I keep getting the error **Cannot find REPL for Ruby** when trying to run sublimeREPL.

I set the default path to:

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH}"}
}
```

This is my path variable in windows:

```
 ;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Ruby21\bin
```

I get this error when I try to run "Eval in REPL" in the Sublime Console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_plugin.py", line 550, in run_
    return self.run(edit, **args)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeREPL\text_transfer.py", line 123, in run
    for rv in manager.find_repl(external_id):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeREPL\sublimerepl.py", line 437, in find_repl
    if not (rv.repl and rv.repl.is_alive()):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeREPL\repls\subprocess_repl.py", line 185, in is_alive
    return self.popen.poll() is None
  File "./subprocess.py", line 938, in poll
  File "./subprocess.py", line 1153, in _internal_poll
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

If I specifically go to **Tools > SublimeREPL > Ruby > Ruby - IRB (Deprecated)**

I get error: 
`Error trying to parse settings: Expected ':' in Packages\User\SublimeREPL.sublime-     settings:2:45`

However, IRB will work and I can evaluate expressions in it.

If I go to the other Ruby option, I get the same message but the REPL doesn't work at all:

```
C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Ruby/pry_repl.rb:37:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Pry::InputCompleter (NameError)

***Repl Closed***
```

Comment: Got that **NameError** too. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: No, I gave up on this.

Comment: Found a pull request would fix it. Check out my answer.

Comment: This error is not only in windows, it's also in Linux

Answer (score 1):

This pull request fixed it. But since the author haven't merge it, you should do it yourself.

By:

```
1. Add **require 'pry/input_completer'** below **require 'pry'**
2. Change on Line 20: **def puts(data="")**          -> **def print(data="")**
3. Change on Line 38: **build_completion_proc(...)** -> **new(...)**
```

This works fine only for **pry>0.10**.

https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/pull/372

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 8, then this is a known problem.  See the following link on the REPL development page:

https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/issues/271